# Laravel eloquent orm - model inheritance

Tags: laravel, eloquent

I am in a team of developers where we are going to develop a timetable application. There are two entities instructor and student. Student has id , firstname , lastname , class, email and phone number whereas the instructor has id , firstname , lastname , subject, email and phone number. There are common fields for instructor and student. Therefore i would like to have a parent entity called users which can include the common fields like id , firstname, lastname , email and phone number. and the student class will have the student specific information such as class, instructor will have their specific information such as subject. I dont know how to do this in laravel as I couldnt find any proper solution online. I think this is a common problem everyone could have. Any suggestions will be appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: You can use polymorphic relation - read this and come back with questions: http://softonsofa.com/how-to-store-clients-in-database-that-is-party-model-implemented-in-laravel-4-part-1/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [object inheritance](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.inheritance.php) in PHP, User class will extend Eloquent and Student class extends User, this way student instances will inherit user attributes as well as being able to define new attributes and functions for students.

```
class User extends Eloquent{
    //id, firstname, lastname..
}

class Student extends User{
    //class, instructor, ..
}
```

Comment: how will it work when i try to retrieve a user by passing their ID , i want to know whether the user is a student or instructor so that i can redirect them to the right dashboard

Comment: I see two solutions here, you could either decide to never use User classes itself, but always Student or Instructor instances. Then you can easily know whether the User is actually a Student or an Instructor :
`if ($user instanceof Student) { redirect()->route('students.dashboard'); }`.

Or you can add a field (enum for instance) in the table class that will check it.
`if ($user->discriminator === 'Student') { redirect()->route('students.dashboard'); }`